# Fantasy story of girl with an obsidian tattoo and an alien spirit wolf

Tags: story-identification, books

The protagonist of the story is a girl with an obsidian tattoo. There is some mentioning of an alien spirit wolf.

If I don't recall wrongly, the story is partly about some type of alien lifeform with no physical bodies possessing human beings and thus slowly developing emotions.

I never got to the end of the story and I think it's part of a series.

If it helps, the book I saw in the library has a girl with a tattoo on the cover.

Comment: Obsidian Tattoo and Alien Spirit Wolf would be awesome band names.

Comment: Was the tattoo just very black, or was it actually made out of obsidian?